# Rank issues in Lineplot PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

So I have been working on a powerbi project and I am new to this so just exploring. I have orders table, customers table,date table along with few other tables and I have created measures for metrics like Order count, Order quantity, LIFR%,VOFR%,OTIF%, etc. What I want to do is, plot a linechart of every metric with time (from date table) but only top N customers.

For eg : If I select LIFR% on the slicer, I want the linechart to have top N customers lines vs timeframe. Then if I select Order count then I want the plot to dynamically change the data and legend both.

One thing which I did is, x axis date, y axis metric, legend customer_name then used visual filter on customer name and opted for Top N filtering and added the metric measure in the "by" field. This works correctly, the only problem being, I have to hard code the N value. I have created a numeric slicer parameter but I dont know how to go further.

Comment: Is your question on how to use a Numeric range parameter to adjust the TOPN (top 5, top 10 etc...). Or is it how to use a Fields parameter for the field/metric being TOPN'd?